# ruby : if i declare a variable in a method does another method in the same class know it exists?

Tags: ruby, class, methods

If i have a method called roll (as in a dice) and it has a variable called number.

can another method in the same class called stats use that variable in it ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
class Die
  def roll
    @number = 5
  end

  def stats
    puts @number
  end
end

d = Die.new
d.roll
d.stats # prints 5
```

Comment: you didnt answer my question. my question was if i call the stats method in your example above will it print the value of the die ??

Comment: @GerCrowley ... ummm ... I am confused.  Yes.  This is how you do it.  Is this not working for you?

Comment: I think what @BrianGenisio means is that, if you add a `@` before your variable, this variable, let's say `@number`, become an instance variable. That means you can access this variable everywhere in this class.

Comment: +1 for question and answer just for make me knowing that the singular for "dice" is "die" (I was wondering about "douse" as in "mouse"...).